# QEMU-KVM guest rootfs read-only issue

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, kvm

While setting up kernel environment using qemu, I can boot into guest, but rootfs is mount as `'read-only filesystem'` . Thus simple command 
like `touch ~/a.txt` fails inside guest.

I tried below with and without sudo permission without any success.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -drive file=~/fs.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -append "root=/dev/sda" --enable-kvm
```

Even after changing *~/fs.img* permission from 644 to 666

```
$ ls -l ~/btrfs.img
-rw-rw-rw- 1 laks laks 1073741824 Dec 22 11:29 ~btrfs.img
```

Any thoughts on what am i missing here? thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution after some more google searching. Append `rw` to the root device. Use `"root=/dev/sda rw"` instead of `"root=/dev/sda"`